# Logitech C270 webcam reading from wrong position

Tags: webcam

Have got my Logitech C270 webcam working out of the box for cheese, skype and it's working fine, sound as well.
But when I go to a website stream it is looking for my camera here; file/dev/video0
the trouble is everything else is say my webcam is here instead; file/dev/video1 
So it works ok on Skype with those settings but other sites are looking for cam in the wrong place?
Thanks now for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a /dev/video0 that's not connected to anything. `sudo rm /dev/video0` and then reboot and you should see your device added in the `/dev/video0` position; if not check `dmesg` for clues.

It's also possible that you've [used **udev** to manually assign](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715333/assign-webcam-to-a-specific-dev-video) a video1 number.

Comment: I realise this is very old question but there's no flag for "super old question" so I had a go ...