# Assign webcam to a specific /dev/video#

Tags: webcam, udev

I have three webcams on my Ubuntu server 14.04.
The output of lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2537:1066
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1871:0101 Aveo Technology Corp. UVC camera (Bresser microscope)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0807 Logitech, Inc. Webcam B500
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1871:0101 Aveo Technology Corp. UVC camera (Bresser microscope)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I want to assign a specific /dev/video# to each one. I have read that I have to create a udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/, but most of what I've read seems outdated and I don't want to cause problems to my server.
I was thinking of creating a 25-name-video-devices.rules containing the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1871", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video10"
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1871", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video11"
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="046d", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0807", NAME="video12"
```

The additional problem I have is that 2 of the 3 webcams seem identical (although they are not, they are bought from ebay and they are used to monitor a different area).
So what would be the rules for my case?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Solution without Udev Rules

There is a chance that video4linux has already provided you with stable device names. You may want to check the directories `/dev/v4l/by-id/` and `/dev/v4l/by-path/` for this. Connect your devices to different USB ports and compare the created device names to make sure that they are really stable.

## Solution with Udev Rules

Otherwise it depends on whether your two seemingly identical devices do at least have a different serial number which is accessible by udev. You can find this out by using the correct “Bus” and “Device” number from your `lsusb` output in the following command:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/bus/usb/003/005
```

If there is some kind of output like the following in the first block of key/value pairs and the serial is different between the two devices, then you may use that in your udev rules:

> ATTR{serial}=="68974689267119892"

Your udev rules could then look like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="68974689267119892", ATTR{idVendor}=="1871", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video10"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="12345698798725654", ATTR{idVendor}=="1871", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video11"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{idProduct}=="0807", NAME="video12"
```

If there is *no* serial (or similar unique) number, then I only see the following possibility: you would have to make sure that your devices always remain connected at the same USB ports. In that case you could use rules like these:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="2-3", ATTR{idVendor}=="1871", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video10"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="2-4", ATTR{idVendor}=="1871", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", NAME="video11"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="2-2", ATTR{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{idProduct}=="0807", NAME="video12"
```

You would have to find out which `KERNEL` IDs to use by again running the `udevadm` command mentioned above and looking for the `KERNEL` key/value pair.

### Minor Notes

It may be nicer/better to only create new symlinks instead of new device names, and maybe even grouping them under a common directory:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="2-3", ATTR{idVendor}=="1871", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", SYMLINK+="foo/video10"
```

The previous rule, for example, would create a device symlink at `/dev/foo/video10`.

I would probably also simply name the rules file `name-video-devices.rules`, i.e., leaving the leading number out. It probably doesn’t matter when the rules are executed, so no need to use a (rather high) priority of 25.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that NAME cannot be changed, except in the special case of network devices. From `man udev`:
`NAME  The name to use for a network interface. The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.`

From `udevadm test <devpath>`:
`NAME="/dev/video99" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-blah.rules:5`