# udev rule seems not working properly to force the usb device into fix location

Tags: usb, mount, webcam, udev, lsusb

I've created a udev rule to force my usb devices into fixed folders at `/dev/`
(one, is a webcam into `/dev/video1` and the other one is a framegrabber into `/dev/video0` ) I need to do this because, by default, I attach webcam after the framegrabber into my computer (so far so good) but if I reboot the system (while they're still attached) the webcam will be assigned to `/dev/video0` and the framegrabber to `/dev/video1` which will lead to the failure of the apps trying to use them as recording resources (gstreamer pipeline, in this case)

I put the `25-video-devices.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and reload the udev rules, even restart the udev service but after rebooting the system the result is still the same...

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="5555", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3500", NAME:="video0", OPTIONS:="link_priority=100"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0843", NAME:="video1"
```

It seems udev rule doesn't function properly or I'm doing something wrong or missing something?

Can you please help me with that?

p.s: I got the vendor and product ids using `lsusb`

Answer (score 4):

From [`man 7 udev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/udev.7.html) (highlighting by me):

> The kernel usually just assigns unpredictable device names based on the order of discovery. […] **The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.**

In other words, I think you won’t be able to use `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video1` reliably. Instead you should create and use stable symlinks. Something like the following might work instead:

```
KERNEL=="video*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="5555", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3500", SYMLINK+="myframegrabber"
KERNEL=="video*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0843", SYMLINK+="mywebcam"
```

You would then use `/dev/mywebcam` and `/dev/myframegrabber` in your applications.

By the way, as recently mentioned in [a similar answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/715417/137449):

> There is a chance that video4linux has already provided you with stable device names. You may want to check the directories `/dev/v4l/by-id/` and `/dev/v4l/by-path/` for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful info :-) I did make symlinks as you mentioned but gstreamer failed to find access to the resources
I checked the /dev/ and saw those links are created but with this permissions: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          13 Jan  9 18:17 mywebcam -> snd/controlC2` how can I fix this as well? does this has something to do with permissions or I'm wrong?

Comment: and here is the permissions on one of the `/dev/video` locations: `crw-rw----+ 1 root video    81,   1 Jan  9 18:16 video1`

Comment: A symlink _always_ has these permissions; it’s the permissions of the link target that matters. Interestingly, your symlink points to `/dev/snd/controlC2` which doesn’t seem to be a video device! Are you sure that your `idVendor` and `idProduct` values are correct? Perhaps the issue is also that the device is internally treated as different devices (both audio and video capturing), not sure. If the latter should be the case, then maybe adding `KERNEL=="video*"` to your rules might help (but this is only a wild guess of mine).

Comment: Well, I did add the `KERNEL=="video*"` to my rules, after rebooting myframegrabber points toward `/dev/video1` and mywebcam to `/dev/video0` which is still wrong...

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you have a symlink `/dev/myframegrabber` now which points to `/dev/video1`? Are you sure that `ATTRS{idVendor}=="5555", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3500"` really reference your framegrabber? What happens if you switch `SYMLINK+="myframegrabber"` and `SYMLINK+="mywebcam"` in the two rules?

Comment: yes, I check it via `lsusb` which is `Bus 002 Device 006: ID 5555:3500 Epiphan Systems Inc.` and just to be sure I checked it via `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video0)` the result was the same

Comment: switching the value of SYMLINK shows something which look right but it appears not because if I remove the webcam I see `/dev/video0` is gone and video1 is assigned to framegrabber

Comment: Wait, we should clarify our expectations here: the _only_ expectation we should have is that `/dev/mywebcam` points to your webcam and `/dev/myframegrabber` points to your framegrabber. It does’t matter what `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video0` point to! The whole purpose of the new rules is to become independent of the latter two device node names and to instead only use the new symlinks. I have updated my answer to what seems to be the solution for your device IDs. Could you please check if your applications can use `/dev/mywebcam` for the webcam and `/dev/myframegrabber` for the framegrabber?